# How can I make Google Chrome automatically translate a page?

Tags: google-chrome, translation

If I visit a page that isn't in my native language, how can I make Google Chrome translate it automatically for me into my native language?

Do I need to change any settings, if so where can I find them?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/206019/set-chromium-to-always-automatically-translate-all-languages ( though this is for OS X)

Answer (score 42):

If you have already chosen "Don't translate this page", the prompt won't come up.

You can right-click and there should be a translation option available.

[image]

You may have to check the translation bar that drops down to make sure the source language is correct.

Comment: I wonder if there is a workaround for web-sites that disable right-click on the page =/
Upd.: found it, you can use _Offer to translate pages that aren't in a language you read_ option in chrome settings then ^_^

Answer (score 6):

When you visit a page in Chrome where the language doesn't match your locale, Chrome will prompt you to translate the page content:

[image: screenshot]

As you can see, my locale is English, and when I visit this page in French, Chrome offers to translate the content for me. When I click the *Translate* button, it will perform an inline translation of the content, and allow you to hover over a word or phrase and see the original content:

[image: final translation]

If this doesn't happen automatically, make sure that in Chrome's preferences, the option to automatically translate is selected.

[image: preference]

Comment: So you don't have to change any settings or download extensions?

Comment: @Ivo - no, you do not need to install any extensions. Just update Chrome settings if needed.

Answer (score 0):

If not done automatically, you can use [this: Chrome Google Translate extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/aapbdbdomjkkjkaonfhkkikfgjllcleb).