# Extension/Script to manually alter page's language tag in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, localization, google-chrome-extensions

Many non-English websites I visit can be translated manually by right-click "Translate" in Google Chrome (despite Chrome seeing it as "Detected Language" it does correctly translate it).

But these pages never get auto-translated despite me having enabled "Always Translate". It seems that if the page HTML specifies its own language correctly (in HTML tag or header meta tags), Chrome will recognize this and auto-translate without me having to initiate the translation.

Many sites I visit are either missing these language tags or they are incorrectly used (example: en_US might have been coded as US_en, just for example).

Is there some extension or method of injecting the correct tags, or overriding the incorrect ones, in Chrome?

I see multiple page code injecting extensions in the Chrome Store, but I can't seem to get them to work properly for what I want. The codes never seem to get injected. Maybe I'm using the wrong syntax.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set Chromium to always automatically translate all languages](https://superuser.com/questions/206019/set-chromium-to-always-automatically-translate-all-languages)

Comment: @Rubén I'm afraid not. The problem seems to be that the websites are not identifying themselves as any particular language, or as the wrong language. That method looks to assume the sites are identifying their own language.

Comment: Have read both answers? Have you already tried the Google Translate Chrome extension?

Comment: I have the extension installed already, but the interface shown in that answer is out of date. There are no such options in the extension itself. That functionality has moved into Chrome proper. Regardless, the issue isn't with Chrome's translation ability itself; it's with the page identifying itself incorrectly.